# Tiny MCE Safari, IE<8 problem

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, tinymce

I am facing a weird problem with TinyMCE. I have incorporated tiny mce for my reply area and when the page loads for the very first time it doesn't show the tiny mce rich text editor the moment i refresh the page the rich text editor is visible.

This problem come on Safari all the versions, IE version less than 8.

Firefox everything works fine.

Any help will be really beneficial.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be helpful if you show the code you're using to include the editor.
My feeling is that some resources (images maybe) are not loaded at the point you try to display the text editor, so it doesn't show up. Once they're loaded (after the refresh) everything works fine.

Comment: The tiny MCE textarea comes correctly on Firefox, IE, Safari 4 on Windows. The real problem is with safari 4 on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved this problem yet, but I had this issue as well and here was my solution:

In the TinyMCE init there is most likely a plugin that is loading improperly, you will need to remove the plugin. Often it is the 'flash' plugin.

Also, the newest version of TinyMCE (currently at 3.3) has much better support for webkit browsers.